# Sort by alphabetical order using pg_search with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, full-text-search

I'm trying to use [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) in my Rails application to sort a list of parts based on a query from a user. I've run into some trouble, though -- I can't seem to get correct results from an ascending order search.

Here's my model:

```
class Pcdb::Part < CatalogsRecord
  include PgSearch
  self.table_name = "parts"
  belongs_to :parts_description
  pg_search_scope :search_for_parts, against: :part_terminology_name,
                   using: { tsearch: { dictionary: "simple", prefix: true } }
end
```

In my controller, I have the following code:

`Pcdb::Part.search_for_parts(query)` where the `query` parameter is input from a user.

I've tried using `query.order("parts.part_terminology_name ASC")` to no avail.

Right now, this is the result I get if the `query` parameter is "Windshield Wiper":

```
Windshield Wiper Motor And Windshield Washer Pump Assembly
Windshield Wiper Motor Relay
Windshield Wiper Switch
Windshield Wiper Motor
Windshield Wiper Arm
Windshield Wiper Blade
Windshield Wiper Linkage
Windshield Wiper Linkage Pivot
Windshield Wiper Blade Refill
```

I'm actually trying to achieve a result like this:

```
Windshield Wiper Arm
Windshield Wiper Blade
Windshield Wiper Blade Refill
Windshield Wiper Linkage
Windshield Wiper Linkage Pivot
Windshield Wiper Motor
Windshield Wiper Motor And Windshield Washer Pump Assembly
Windshield Wiper Motor Relay
Windshield Wiper Switch
```

I'd appreciate being pointed in the right direction!

Comment: I haven't used the gem but with that result can you use the active record order method? why don't you give a try?

Comment: You may need to try `reorder` instead of `order`. `reorder` will remove any other ordering defined elsewhere in case that's throwing things off.

Comment: @ellitt That was it. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `reorder` instead of `order`. `reorder` will remove any other ordering defined elsewhere in case that's throwing things off.